# Example of a bounded imperfect PAC field that is not separably closed

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, model-theory, fields

How do you construct a bounded (meaning there are only finitely many separable finite extensions of any given degree) imperfect pseudo-algebraically closed field that is not separably closed? I assume they must exist, since for instance in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007298000219) paper by Zoé Chatzidakis and Anand Pillay they are shown to be simple - in the model theory sense, see [Forking and Dividing](https://www.forkinganddividing.com/) - and this would not be an interesting assertion about separably closed fields since they were known to be stable for a long time. In Fried-Jarden there is a chapter on PAC fields of positive characteristics, but it does not seem to bother with constructions.

Comment: What does "bounded" mean in this context?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer in the paper linked - a bounded field $F$ is one which has only finitely many separable extensions of degree $n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question to include that, thanks!

Comment: Every infinite, proper subfield $k$ of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is a "bounded" PAC field that is not separably closed.  Of course these are perfect.  But then you can apply the construction in the following MO post to produce a field extension $K/k$ that is imperfect PAC and that has the same finite field extensions as $k$ (hence $K$ is bounded and not separably closed): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407532/countably-many-isomorphism-classes-of-reductive-groups-over-a-field-with-countab/407609#407609

Comment: I just realized that the field $K$ in my previous comment is perfect after all (since it has the same field extensions as $k$, and these are all separable).  To get a valid example, begin with $k$ equal to a bounded, imperfect field, e.g., the compositum of all finite Galois extensions of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}((t))$ whose Galois group is a $p$-group.

Comment: Thanks! That should work! If you want to give it as an answer I will happily accept it, I also found a different less concrete example I will answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

To me it was slightly surprising to find out that in a sense this is a very typical example. The $\mathrm{PAC}$ Nullstellensatz, for instance treated in Fried-Jarden [1] implies:

> Let $K$ be a countable Hilbertian field and $e$ a positive integer. Then the fixed field of an automorphism $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K)$ is $\mathrm{PAC}$ for almost all $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K)$.

Also note Theorem 18.5.6. of the same book:

> Let $K$ be a Hilbertian field and $e$ a positive integer. Then $\langle \sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n \rangle \simeq \hat{F}_e$ for almost all $(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n) \in \mathrm{Gal}(K)^e$

Note that in both of these theorem "for almost all" means "the set of elements not fulfilling this requirement has Haar-measure 0".

Together this gives that for almost all $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(K)$ the fixed field of $\sigma$ is $\mathrm{PAC}$ and has absolute Galois group $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, so it is bounded. If we start with an imperfect countable Hilbertian field, for instance every function field over an infinite field of characteristic $p$, then this will give many imperfect bounded $\mathrm{PAC}$ fields, although in a very non-constructive manner.

<sub>[1]: Field Arithmetic, Michael D. Fried, Moshe Jarden, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-77270-5</sub>

Comment: Yes, this theorem is how Koll'ar used to explain the ubiquity of PAC fields when he was lecturing about his proof of Ax's conjecture in characteristic $0$ (it is also "mostly" proved in positive characteristic -- true if the field contains $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ or if we work with $2$-Fano complete intersections rather than Fano complete intersections).